# Dir and file created by python program doesn’t show up in Windows ’ explorer

Tags: python

I use sqlite with python program.
To create and locate the db file I do this

```
home_directory = os.path.expanduser( '~' )
os.mkdir(home_directory+"\AppData\Local\\myprog")

db_url="sqlite:///"+home_directory+"\AppData\Local\\myprog\db1"
```

The database file seems to be created as I can retrieve data after closing and restarting the application.
Nevertheless, when I visit the Local dir in the user’s AppData I do not see the created myprog dir.

Comment: What happens if you add `import os; os.startfile(home_directory+"\AppData\Local\\myprog")` to your code?

Comment: I added your suggestion after the 3 lines of code and the error message is (translated from French language) Location not available C.Users\33604\AppData\Local\myprog is not available. If this location is on this PC, be sure the drive or reader is connected or that the disk is inserted. If the location is on a network......if the location cannot be found, it means it may have been displaced or deleted.

Comment: If I add \\db1 after the path an invite to choose the type of application to use in order to open the file shows up

Comment: Choosing NotePad gives this error message "The specified path has not been found" (translated from French)

Comment: Instead of a sqlite db I created a text file. It can be retrieved after closing the app but the behavior in the explorer is the same. Not visible.

Comment: I don’t know if it matters but my python is in virtual env

Comment: I eventually made out that the dir and file are created in C:\Users\33604\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\Local. I don’t know how to prevent this. Elsewhere this doesn’t occur if the dir is created outside AppData in an other folder under the user dir.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to say that I was running the application from VSCode not the installed app.
I tried to run the .exe produced by pyinstaller and everything is good. The folder and the db are created at the right place i.e. AppData\Local.